# after clicking child window, cant interact with parent window

Tags: winapi, direct2d

I created a button. After i click the button, it works but after clicking i cant interact with main window(such as pressing arrow key). when i click outside main window (killing focus on main window), then i click main window(focus on main window) then i can interact with main window. i dont know what's going on.
here is the code
[Link](https://github.com/IceWind233/Direct2D_2048)
and the button creates as following.

```
inline void Button::create_button() {
    const auto _button_width = button_wrapper_.right - button_wrapper_.left;
    const auto _button_height = button_wrapper_.bottom - button_wrapper_.top;

    auto _button_hwnd = CreateWindow(
        L"Button",
        text_,
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
        button_wrapper_.left,
        button_wrapper_.top,
        _button_width,
        _button_height,
        parent_hwnd_,
        nullptr,
        reinterpret_cast<HINSTANCE>(GetWindowLongPtr(parent_hwnd_, GWLP_HINSTANCE)),
        nullptr);

}
```

I tried to refocus main windows after click button but it not works.
I tried to create button as Win32 tutorial and it still not work(maybe i misunderstand it?)

Comment: Just a wild guess: Your child and parent window are owned by different threads. If you need an answer that doesn't have to guess, show a [mcve].

Comment: The button steals the focus. You don't see it because you draw over it w/o some focus indicator. In your code the easiest is to `SetFocus(m_hwnd_)` just after `BN_CLICKED` + `board_controller_.reset_board();` see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519150/c-window-losing-focus-when-child-button-is-pressed

Comment: This question is useless now. There's a reason why we require that you provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the button "steals the focus" when we click on it, so the window doesn't receive WM_KEYDOWN messages any more. This is by design. See also this on SO: [C++ Window losing focus when child button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519150/c-window-losing-focus-when-child-button-is-pressed)

There are multiple way to fix it, but in this case the easier is to add a [SetFocus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setfocus) call, right after the button has been clicked, like this:

```
case WM_COMMAND: {
        switch (LOWORD(w_param)) {
        case BN_CLICKED: {
            board_controller_.reset_board();
            SetFocus(m_hwnd_); // add this here to give focus back to window
            break;
        }
        }
        return 0;
```